# invalid use of non-static member C++98

Tags: c++, class, pointers, c++98

I'm writing a C++ program that, unfortunately, requires the use of a C++98 compiler. After writing the program and trying to compile I get this error:

`error: invalid use of non-static data member 'graph::adj_list'`

This is confusing to me since I used cppreference (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members) to make sure this would compile. Can anybody help me out?

graph_frame.h

```
#include <cstddef>


class node{
friend class graph;
private:
    int node_name;
    int edge_weight;
    node *next_cell = NULL;
    node *previous_cell = NULL;

public:
    node(int name = 0, int new_edge = 0);
    ~node();
};


class graph{
private:
    void recursive_delete(int i, int k);
    node** adj_list;                     <----------------ERROR

public:
    //----argument not needed for constructor because a list is not created
    //----until create_graph() is called
    graph();
    ~graph();
    //----remember to free all buckets from list
    void create_graph(int& graph_nodes);
    int check_node(int& source_node, int& dest_node);
    void insert_node(int& source_node, int& dest_node, int& weight);
    void print(node **dummy = adj_list, int i = 0, int k = 0);
    void delete_node(int& source_node, int& dest_node);
};
```

Comment: The error is referring to *void print(node **dummy = `adj_list`, int i = 0, int k = 0);*

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Is there another way to say "use adj_list as your pointer base for this default argument"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
node *next_cell = NULL;
node *previous_cell = NULL;
```

That won't fly - in-class initializers for non-static members were only introduced in C++11.

About `adj_list`, the real location of the error is here:

```
void print(node **dummy = adj_list, int i = 0, int k = 0);
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^
```

You can't have a class member as a default value because it's not known to which instance it should belong. You can't use `this` there either, so you'll have to figure out some other way to pass a default value.

Comment: How about a class function that returns the address of 'adj_list' and I can use that for all instances of print?

Comment: @Raspberry: How about making the argument non-optional, and adding a zero-argument overload `void print() { return print(adj_list); }`  Also, why isn't `print` marked `const`?

Comment: @RaspberryPeanut No. That's just another variation of the same problem. I suggest you write another overload that doesn't take a `node**` as parameter and then use `adj_list` in the body.

Comment: @BenVoigt It's not marked `const` because I missed it. I was just concerned about getting working code first.

Comment: @jrok aka basically move `node **dummy = adj_list` into the function body so it doesn't have weird parameter problems?